# In sqlx, why objects of type "query_db::{closure#0}::Record" are considered having different types?

Tags: rust-sqlx

When using sqlx, I have a `match` block as follows:

```
    let messages_option = match time_range {
        TimeRange {before: Some(before), after: Some(after)} => {
            sqlx::query!("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE timestamp BETWEEN ? AND ?", after, before)
                .fetch_all(&mut conn)
                .await
        },
        TimeRange {before: None, after: Some(after)} => {
            sqlx::query!("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE timestamp > ?", after)
                .fetch_all(&mut conn)
                .await
        },
        TimeRange {before: Some(before), after: None} => {
            sqlx::query!("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE timestamp < ?", before)
                .fetch_all(&mut conn)
                .await
        },
        TimeRange {before: None, after: None} => {
            sqlx::query!("SELECT * FROM messages")
                .fetch_all(&mut conn)
                .await
        }
    };
```

When building, it gives the following error:

```
135 |       let messages_option = match time_range {
    |                             ---------------- `match` arms have incompatible types
136 |           TimeRange {before: Some(before), after: Some(after)} => {
137 | /             sqlx::query!("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE timestamp BETWEEN ? AND ?", after, before)
138 | |                 .fetch_all(&mut conn)
139 | |                 .await
    | |______________________- this is found to be of type `Result<Vec<query_db::{closure#0}::Record>, sqlx::Error>`
...
142 | /             sqlx::query!("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE timestamp > ?", after)
143 | |                 .fetch_all(&mut conn)
144 | |                 .await
    | |______________________^ expected `query_db::{closure#0}::Record`, found a different `query_db::{closure#0}::Record`
    |
    = note: expected enum `Result<Vec<query_db::{closure#0}::Record>, _>` (`query_db::{closure#0}::Record`)
               found enum `Result<Vec<query_db::{closure#0}::Record>, _>` (`query_db::{closure#0}::Record`)
```

It says "expected `query_db::{closure#0}::Record`, found a different `query_db::{closure#0}::Record`", but the types look exactly the same, then why the incompatibility?

Please help.
Thanks!